# Random memory write is slower than random memory read?

Tags: performance, x86-64, cpu-cache, memory-bandwidth

I'm trying to figure out memory access time of sequential/random memory read/write. Here's the code:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PRINT_EXCECUTION_TIME(msg, code)                                       \
  do {                                                                         \
    struct timeval t1, t2;                                                     \
    double elapsed;                                                            \
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);                                                   \
    do {                                                                       \
      code;                                                                    \
    } while (0);                                                               \
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);                                                   \
    elapsed = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;                                \
    elapsed += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;                             \
    printf(msg " time: %f ms\n", elapsed);                                     \
  } while (0);

const int RUNS = 20;
const int N = (1 << 27) - 1;
int *data;

int seqR() {
  register int res = 0;
  register int *data_p = data;
  register int pos = 0;

  for (register int j = 0; j < RUNS; j++) {
    for (register int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      pos = (pos + 1) & N;
      res = data_p[pos];
    }
  }

  return res;
}

int seqW() {
  register int res = 0;
  register int *data_p = data;
  register int pos = 0;

  for (register int j = 0; j < RUNS; j++) {
    for (register int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      pos = (pos + 1) & N;
      data_p[pos] = res;
    }
  }

  return res;
}

int rndR() {
  register int res = 0;
  register int *data_p = data;
  register int pos = 0;

  for (register int j = 0; j < RUNS; j++) {
    for (register int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      pos = (pos + i) & N;
      res = data_p[pos];
    }
  }

  return res;
}

int rndW() {
  register int res = 0;
  register int *data_p = data;
  register int pos = 0;

  for (register int j = 0; j < RUNS; j++) {
    for (register int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      pos = (pos + i) & N;
      data_p[pos] = res;
    }
  }

  return res;
}

int main() {
  data = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (N + 1));
  assert(data);

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    data[i] = i;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    PRINT_EXCECUTION_TIME("seqR", seqR());
    PRINT_EXCECUTION_TIME("seqW", seqW());
    PRINT_EXCECUTION_TIME("rndR", rndR());
    PRINT_EXCECUTION_TIME("rndW", rndW());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I used `gcc 6.5.0` with `-O0` to prevent optimization but got result like this:

```
seqR time: 2538.010000 ms
seqW time: 2394.991000 ms
rndR time: 40625.169000 ms
rndW time: 46184.652000 ms
seqR time: 2411.038000 ms
seqW time: 2309.115000 ms
rndR time: 41575.063000 ms
rndW time: 46206.275000 ms
```

It's easy to understand that sequential access is way faster than random access. However, it doesn't make sense to me that random write is slower than random read while sequential write is faster than sequential read. What reason could cause this?

In addition, am I safe to say memory bandwidth for `seqR` is `(20 * ((1 << 27) - 1) * 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)GB / (2.538)s = 4.12GB/s`?

Comment: What processor did you use to run the experiments?

Comment: It seems to me that `data_p[N]` may be accessed in all of the four functions. You may want to allocate N+1 `int`s.

Comment: Thanks, it should be `N + 1`. I'm using Intel Xeon E5-2695 v4 Broadwell.

Comment: @zingdle: oh.  Many-core Xeon is notoriously bad for single-threaded memory bandwidth vs. a quad-core desktop.  4GB/s is still lower than I'd expect, though, so I still think you're CPU-bound (not memory) in the sequential functions.  See [Why is Skylake so much better than Broadwell-E for single-threaded memory throughput?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39260020)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, it looks like the original code is CPU-bound. I changed the array to `volatile`, removed the `register` and recompiled with `O3`. The assembly told me it uses some `xmm` registers to optimize but the time spent is roughly the same as before. If I omit `pos = (pos + i) & N;` and access array with `data[i]`, the time spent halves. However, I cannot directly compare random/sequential memory access time like before.

Comment: @zingdle: you didn't need to remove `register`; it's not harmful.  It's basically ignored by the optimizer with optimization enabled.  It might make it illegal to take the address of the variable in C, like `const` makes it illegal to assign, but when optimization is enabled compilers will already check if that happens anywhere in the function.

Comment: Anyway, removing the `(pos + 1) & N` shortens the loop-carried dependency chain from increment and mask to just increment.  Since x86 doesn't have an inc-and-mask instruction, it was presumably bottlenecked at 2 cycles per iteration on an `inc` / `and` dependency chain for `pos`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds normal.  All x86-64 CPUs (and most other modern CPUs) use write-back / write-allocate caches so a write costs a read before it can commit to cache, and an eventual write-back.

> with `-O0` to prevent optimization

Since you used `register` on all your locals, this is one of the rare times when this didn't make your benchmark meaningless.

You could have just used `volatile` on your arrays, though, to make sure every one of those accesses happened in order, but leave it up to the optimizer how to make that happen.

> Am I safe to say memory bandwidth for seqR is `(20 * ((1 << 27) - 1) * 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)GB / (2.538)s` = `4.12GB/s`?

No, you have an extra factor of 2^30 and 10^9 in your numerator.  But you did it wrong and got close to the right number anyway.

The correct calculation is `RUNS * N * sizeof(int) / time` bytes per second, or that *divided* by 10^9 GB/s.  Or divided by 2^30 for base 2 GiB/s.  Memory sizes are usually in GiB, but you can take your pick with bandwidth; DRAM clock speeds are normally things like 1600 MHz, so base-10 GB = 10^9 is certainly normal for theoretical max bandwidths in GB/s.)

So 4.23 GB/s in base-10 GB.

Yes, you initialized the array first so neither timed run is triggering page-faults, but I might still have used the 2nd run after the CPU has warmed up to max turbo, if it hadn't already.

But keep in mind this is un-optimized code.  That's how fast your un-optimized code ran, and doesn't tell you much about how fast your memory is.  It's probably CPU bound, not memory.

Especially with a redundant `& N` in there to match the CPU work of the `rndR/W` functions.  HW prefetching is probably able to keep up with 4GB/s, but it's still not even reading 1 `int` per clock cycle.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Agreed, that's why I said so in my answer :P  But keeping it there is maybe good to control for differences between the instruction counts in the seq vs. rnd loops.

Comment: I learned a lot from this brilliant answer, thank you! I just want to compare the performance difference between sequential/random access so there are redundant `register`, `& N` and `O0`. But I'm still unsure about why sequential write is slightly faster than read since it's also using write-back / write-allocate.

Comment: @zingdle: `register` is *not* redundant if you're going to compile with `-O0`.  That's the one time the `register` keyword is useful.  With GCC it stops the variable from being kept in memory and putting store-forwarding store/reload latency into a loop-carried dependency chain.  (Have a look at the generated asm; the loop structure is probably still crap, but at least it isn't keeping loop vars in memory.)

Comment: @zingdle: I think sequential write is faster because the store buffer can help hide occasional bubbles.  Like I said, your code is nowhere near bottlenecking on actual memory / cache bandwidth, so HW prefetch into L2 can easily keep up.  (Unless your CPU is ancient).  You'll only get stalls at page boundaries.  Loads have to complete before they can retire from the out-of-order back-end, but stores have to retire *before* they can commit to L1d.  (The store buffer isolates cache from speculative execution).

Comment: So normally memory can keep up with this slow stream of read+write-back, and when you do hit a bubble the store-buffer gives extra space to absorb it.  Other than cache-miss stalls, the store-buffer can drain faster than your code can fill it so it's ready to absorb the next stall before it happens.

Comment: @zingdle: or since your sequential loops are presumably CPU-bound, maybe there's an extra uop in the load vs. the store loop.  What compiler / version / options, so we can try it on https://godbolt.org/ and see what asm you were benchmarking.  Although that would probably make a bigger difference than 1 part in 24 since the loop is probably a lot smaller than that (in uops).

Comment: I'm not so familiar with architecture so I need to read more material about store buffer, uops and all other related new staff. From what I can absorbed now, I believe you mean store buffer can hide latency between stalls. I'm using gcc 6.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 and compile the code with `gcc code.c -O0`. Howerver, godbolt seems don't have 6.5.0. I  have no access to the machine right now but I can paste the asm ASAP.

Comment: @zingdle: It's almost certainly the same as 6.4.0 on Godbolt.  re: uops and microarchitecture, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info and [what is a store buffer?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11105827) / [Size of store buffers on Intel hardware? What exactly is a store buffer?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54876208).  Remember that a load's value is something the CPU may have to wait for.  But a store is the CPU sending data out; it only has to wait if it fills up its buffers.  (out-of-order exec can hide load and store latency if nothing depends on the load, though.)

Comment: I ran the code on Haswell. The numbers are close to what the OP shows (on Broadwell E5), except that the observations don't hold across many runs, i.e., `seqR`/`rndR` is not necessarily faster or slower than `seqW`/`rndW`. In many runs, the difference is within 1%, but it sometimes is a little larger. I think you're right. The sequential loops are probably pipeline-bound (not cache or memory bound) and the random loops appear to be bound by *at least* the number of fill buffers at the L1 (`L1D_PEND_MISS.FB_FULL`). In both cases, the achieved BW is much smaller than the max single-threaded BW.

Comment: I checked the asm and it the same as `x86-64 gcc 6.4` on godbolt.org.