RAM sequential vs random writes of cacheline size
If I write (specifically recent x86 but interesting more generally) to RAM in "batches" with the same size as a cache line (e.g. an AVX512 vector) to memory that is gurenteed to not be read or written by any other thread (so no contention).
Would I expect the same performance writing to random locations as for writing sequentially?
I was originally expecting so (since the writes to memory have no dependency, have cache line size and should be able to be executed in parallel with arithmetic operations by the cpu). However, my tests seems to indicate otherwise.
Here is an example of code I run on a saphire rapids to test the write performance of sequential avx512 locations vs "ranomd" ones which gives me about 500ms per loop for sequential but 1500ms for the random ones which suprised me a lot.
Trying to profile this it seem sas if the random one is much more "core bound" - which I fail to understand, I have the same dependicies in both code paths, the only remaining difference should be how ofthen memory adresses are sequential and not.
#![feature(portable_simd)]
use std::time::Instant;

use ::std::simd::Simd;
use rayon::prelude::*;

type V32 = Simd<f32, 16>;

fn main() {
    let vec_size = 110000000;
    let no_writes: usize = 1000_000_00;
    let no_trials = 10;

    let mut d = vec![];
    d.resize_with(vec_size + 128, || V32::splat(0.0));

    let mut sum: usize = 0;

    println!("sequential   random");
    for _ in 0..no_trials {
        // first the sequential writes
        let mut u1: u32 = 33;
        let mut u2: u32 = 9824;
        let mut i = 0;
        let mut v = V32::splat(1.0);
        let inn = Instant::now();
        for _ in 0..no_writes {
            u1 = 36969 * (u1 & 65535) + (u1 >> 16);
            u2 = 18000 * (u2 & 65535) + (u2 >> 16);
            let j = (u1 << 16) + (u2 & 65535);
            let j = (j as usize % vec_size) as usize;
            let ii = i as usize % vec_size;
            sum += j + ii;
            v += V32::splat(1.0);

            let iii = j / 10000 + ii / 1;
            unsafe { *d.get_unchecked_mut(iii % vec_size) = v };
            //   d[j] = v;

            i += 1;
            }
        let t = inn.elapsed();
        print!("{:?} \t", t);

        // // next the "random" one, we should be memory restrained
        // // so the few integer calculations should not matter
        let mut u1: u32 = 33;
        let mut u2: u32 = 9824;
        let mut i = 0;
        let mut v = V32::splat(1.0);
        let inn = Instant::now();
        for _ in 0..no_writes {
            u1 = 36969 * (u1 & 65535) + (u1 >> 16);
            u2 = 18000 * (u2 & 65535) + (u2 >> 16);
            let j = (u1 << 16) + (u2 & 65535);
            let j = (j as usize % vec_size) as usize;
            let ii = i as usize % vec_size;
            sum += j + ii;
            v += V32::splat(1.0);

            let iii = j / 1 + ii / 10000;
            unsafe { *d.get_unchecked_mut(iii % vec_size) = v };
            //   d[j] = v;

            i += 1;
        }
        let t = inn.elapsed();
        println!("{:?}", t);
    }

    // ensure that everything is not optimized away
    let mut v = 0.0;
    for i in 0..vec_size {
        v += d[i][i % 16];
    }
    println!("");
    println!("{} {}", v, sum);
}


computers are very smart and have learned to predict sequential reads and writes and make them faster a long time ago.

That surely does not apply here? Caching will only have an effect if the memory is accessed for read (pre-fetching) - and here I specifically write only, and in units of cache line size?

no, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57039594/15649230, also you are under the assumption that your code writes to the RAM directly as if you are on a cheap microcontroller, which is not true, the CPU still has to do the whole virt_to_phys thing whenever it hits something that's not directly in cache, there are too many moving parts here

Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12785717/5397009 most Intel processors use a write-back cache, so when you write data, the CPU has to flush a line from the cache, which may trigger a write-back operation if the line was dirty. This write-back operation may be anticipated if your access pattern is predictable, but not if it's too random.

Also with modern memory, the assumption that
cache line writes to memory are independent is not actually true. DDR memory works in rows and banks, which can be kB in size, with significant timing differences for retrieval depending on whether you are accessing the same or different row/bank. Sequential access allows the memory controller to optimise for multiple writes to the same row without reopening it.

Thanks, the last point that ram has banks of kB of size I can understand how that would influence this (and it's interesting, thanks!). However, I fail to understand from the other two links how the write-back cache affects here? Surely that cache is written to memory in cach-line sized items? And there should be no "dirty" problem since this code is the only one operating on these memory adresses?

Or is the write back cache actually written to memory in larger units to account for the banks size in the ram?

This code may be the only one operating on these memory addresses, but there may be other code operating on the same cache lines (including code from the OS and/or other applications).

Yes there might be a little bit, but on an unloaded PC running this code in long loops that cannot statistically explain a x3 factor that some of the cachelines sometimes have som OS work "contention"

On Intel CPUs, 2 cache lines can be loaded (dependent of the CPU). They did that because 1 cache line was not enough to get good performance. This behaves like if a cache line was 128 byte wide, though they can adapt this behaviour based on the memory pressure (and tests on Skylake-like CPUs tends to confirm they actually do that). Thus, using wider blocs can help. Prefetching can also help to reduce the overhead of random accesses. As for random writes aligned on a cache line, you can use streaming store so to avoid reads but this assume data is not read later (i.e. not cached).

Another effect to consider is TLB misses: random accesses typically results in many different pages being read/written and if there is too many pages, then there will be TLB trashing which is expensive (especially if the STLB miss). Using huge pages can help assuming there is enough entries for huge pages in your TLB for this code. For sequential read/writes, the TLB is generally not an issue since only one/few pages are read/written at a time (compared to typically 1 per cache line).

Interesting on the streaming store, googling and looking at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=AVX_512&cats=Store&ig_expand=1335,1615,6464,6477,6510,6540,6527 yields me nothing - do you happen to know what instructions are used to store and bypass cache (so I can test if that imrpoves things)

This is the ones at the end of your linked page: e.g. _mm512_stream_si512 for integers. Note that the latency of streaming store can be higher than classical ones so the throughput can be lower because of a limited concurrency. But the benefit is a better memory usage so the throughput can be actually higher with multiple threads. Performance results are dependent of the specific target CPU (the latency on Xeon CPUs tends to be high due to the one of the L3).

Interesting, thanks, trying this instruction (chaning the "store" part of the code above to:
  unsafe {
    core::arch::x86_64::_mm512_stream_ps(
      d.as_mut_ptr().add(iii % vec_size).cast::<f32>(),
      v.into(),
    )
  }


Does improve the random case a little bit (1200ms instead of 1500ms), but still far off the 500 och the sequential. I guess that means leaves two possible explanations, the "TLB lookup" or the physical properties of the ram. Also of interest is that when i chagne the size of the vec I'm writing to to 600Mb (to large for cache but significantly  smaller considering pages) the performance of the two methofs convge.
I guess that indicates that the problem is the TLB miss you refer to (600Mb is >> kbs of sice of ram banks). Is there any way to profile if this is indeed the problem?

On a recent Linux, running your command with perf stat -e dTLB-loads,dTLB-load-misses,dTLB-stores,dTLB-store-misses,dTLB-prefetches,dTLB-prefetch-misses should give you TLB usage stats.
